# MQTT Broker closing connection as i send connect packet

Tags: mqtt, connect, adafruit

I am using GL865 V3 to connect to broker(io.adafruit.com) and Paho MQTT as library.when ı send connect packet to Broker ,after a few seconds broker closing server connection and ı cant subscribe or publish. I am pretty sure about my connect packet is correct. ı checked all bytes and all true.Here is my connect packet ;

I see that ''GSMModule45 connected'' on Adafruit's monitor but after a few seconds server connection dropping.Thanks for helps.

```
0x10,0x45,0x00,0x04,0x4D 'M',0x51 'Q',0x54 'T',0x54 'T',0x04,0xC2,0x00,0x3C,0x00,0x0B,ClientID,0x00,0x0A,Username,0x00,0x20,Password

ClientID = GSMModule45
Password = 2352877485434906a57a00f745ee62d8
Username = kaansarica
```

What am ı missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

My mistake was that my connect buffer was over size so ı truncated it and my problem solved.